# Which solution is the optimum, using order by or using rank() window function?

Tags: sql, database, sorting

In terms of the performance-boosting, if I want to get the employee with the highest salary in the company I can get that by one of the two following techniques.

- selecting the employee and applying the `order by` clause and then limiting the result to 1

```
select employee from employees order by salary desc limit 1;
```

- Or I can achieve that by using `rank()` window function and get the lowest rank.

```
select employee from (
       select employee, rank() over (order by salary desc) rnk from employees)
where rnk =1
```

I see the first solution is optimum as I apply the sorting algorithm once and get the answer. Instead of selecting from sorted temp data.

I need the experts' opinions.

Comment: If multiple employees have the highest salary, how do you pick which one should be returned? Or, should they all be returned, or is it guaranteed that no 2 employees have the same salary? Also, which RDBMS are you using - please add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: I am asking generally not for a specific RDBMS. You can assume whatever you want, I don't think that would affect the answer dramatically.

Comment: While most RDBMS share most syntax,  some have custom extensions to SQL that may help here. What about my other questions?

Comment: @Bohemian Any assumptions are accepted, I am just thinking about it with you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL, as a declarative language, is about the **"What", not the "How"**.
You declare what you want to get as a result and it is up to the database to decide how to do it depends on your code **as well** as the specific SQL engine, the system configuration, the database configuration, the data demographics, the collected statistics and more.
In some SQL engines you might hint the database as to your preferred execution plan, however, this hint might cause an execution error or be ignored.
I have even seen scenarios where the execution plan did not reflect some optimizations done by the database.

In other words -
Your assumption as to how a database execute your 2 queries might be completely wrong.
There is no reason to assume that the 2nd query will store temp results or even that any of the queries will use sorting at all.

And last -
What you are trying to achieve can actually be done without any sorting with complexity of o(n).

Comment: So you mean, in other words, that I should check the execution plan of the query to know in which order the query will be executed and then to choose which approach to use?

Comment: Basically yes, but as I said in my answer, even that could be ineffective since some SQL engines do not reflect in the execution plan all of the optimizations they are doing behind the scenes, or the execution plan might changed due to an upgrade, data demographic change, statistics collection, system configuration change etc,

Comment: ... and it's not really about "order of execution". The actual execution plan could look very different from you intended to reflect in the way you wrote your query.